# Tabular environment for specified width, bg and font colorings by row?

Tags: tables, fonts, color, width

I'm looking for a tabular-type environment which will allow me to:

- Specify the total width (like `tabular*` or `tabularx`, `tabulary`)
- Allow an individual row to have a specific background color (like `colortbl`)
- Allow all entries in a row to have a specific font or color (like `tabu`)

It seems that each package can do one thing, but is there any super-tabular package which can do all of that?  Otherwise I'm going to have to load them all and hope they play well with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `colortbl` with `tabular*`, `tabularx`, or `tabulary` for the last, use `array` package (which is loaded anyway by tx or ty) and

```
>{\fontcolor}c  >{\fontcolor}l  >{\fontcolor}X
```

where `\fontcolor` is defined by

```
\newcommand\fontcolor{}
```

then when you want a row to use blue text go

```
...\\
\noalign{\gdef\fontcolor{\color{blue}}}
.... text in blue\\
\noalign{\gdef\fontcolor{}}
.. back to black
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is a combination of packages which I can clearly use without having to make much change at all to my current document.